# How can I fix the 'AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'items'' in Redis when using zadd() to add values to a sorted set?

Tags: redis, sortedset

import redis
r= redis.StrictRedis(host="localhost", port=6379, db=0, charset="utf-8", decode_responses=True)
r.zadd("players", 10, "new_player")

"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "...\sorted_set.py", line 6, in 
x= r.zadd("players", 10, "new_player")
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\redis\commands\core.py", line 4109, in zadd
for pair in mapping.items():
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'items'
"""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the documentation of redis-py, the members of the sorted set have to be provided as a dictionary. Full documentation [here](https://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/commands.html#redis.commands.core.CoreCommands.zadd)

The sample code would look like:

```
import redis
r = redis.StrictRedis(host="localhost", port=6379,db=0)
x = r.zadd("players", {"new_player":10})
```